# i want to fill my field on click of combobox in for loop

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to fill my field on click of combobox in for loop. I'm getting this but only in my one row. When I generate another new row it's not taking the value. I have more than one row to fill the field on click of combo. I even try to use this with class but its is not happening.

My html code is

```
<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" id="code" name="code_0" class="code1 form-input-oth"/></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function Expedisi(t) 
   {
      var y = document.getElementById("code");
      y.value = t.value;
    }
</script>
```

The javascript code to do this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function Expedisi(t) 
   {
      var y;
      for(var i=0; i<y.length;i++){ 
      document.getElementById("code").innerHTML=y[i];
      y[i].value = t.value;
      }
   }
</script>
```

But the above code is not working.

```
</table>
<tr>
<table id="detail" border="1px" width="50%" >
<tr>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Item Code</font><span></span></label></td>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Item Name</font><span></span></label></td>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Qty</font><span></span></label></td>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Cost</font><span></span></label></td>
<td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Amount</font><span></span></label></td>
</tr>



<?php
if ($addflag == 0)  {
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `damtran` WHERE vouchno='$getvouch'") or die(mysql_error());

$ctr = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6"  name="sr_' . $ctr . '"  value="' . $row["srno"] . '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>';
   echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code"  name="code_' . $ctr . '"  value="' . $row["code"] . '" class="code1 form-input-oth"/>  </td>';
   echo '<td align="center"><select data-placeholder="Item Name" id="cmbitem" style="width:200px; text-align: left;" name="cmbitem_' . $ctr . '" onChange="Expedisi(this);" class="chzn-select-deselect" >';
   echo "<option value=$geti[code]>$geti[name]</option>";
   $iqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `item` ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($trow = mysql_fetch_array($iqry)) {
   echo "<option value=$trow[code]>$trow[name]</option>";
}

   echo '</select></td>';
   echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6"  maxlength="6" name="qty_' . $ctr . '" value="' . $row["qty"] . '" class="qty form-input-oth"/></td>';
   echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" name="cost_' . $ctr . '" value="' . $row["cost"] . '" class="cost form-input-oth"/></td>';
   echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" size="9" maxlength="6" id="amt" name="amt_' . $ctr . '" value="' . $row["amt"] . '" class="cal form-input-amt"/></td>';
   echo '</tr>';
   $ctr++;
}
} else {
?> 
  <tr>
  <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="sr_0" class="form-input-oth"/></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" id="code" name="code_0" class="code1 form-input-oth"/></td>
  <td align="center"><select data-placeholder="Item Name" style="width:200px; text-align: left;" name="cmbitem_0" onChange="Expedisi(this)"  class="chzn-select-deselect" >
<option value=""></option>
<?php
$iqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `item` ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($trow = mysql_fetch_array($iqry)) {
   echo "<option value=$trow[code]>$trow[name]</option>";
     }
?>
   </select></td>
  <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9"  name="qty_0" class="qty form-input-oth"/></td>
  <td align="right"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9"  name="cost_0" class="cost form-input-oth"/></td>
  <td align="right"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="amt" name="amt_0" class="cal form-input-amt"/></td>
  </tr>


<?php } ?>
  </table>
  <tr>
  <td>
&nbsp;<input type="button" id="addnew" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
<input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $ctr : 1; ?>" />  
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you share your actual code. From where you are calling that function?

Comment: what is y value in second function. please post your full code

Comment: I have posted my full code....

Answer (score 0):

as the code show there stands

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                     function Expedisi(t) 
                     {
                        var y;
                        for(var i=0; i<y.length;i++){ 
                        document.getElementById("code").innerHTML=y[i];
                        y[i].value = t.value;
                        }
                     }
       </script>
```

y is empty so y.length is always going to be 0, in other wordt there is nothing to loop through

Comment: so it will be fine to assign a value to y as y = 0 or y = [] then i will start looping...?

Comment: no, the loop should not be based on a variable you are assigning data to it should be based on the length of the data you want to itterate through, i suggest that you read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: what does the variable t contain becuase i suspect that t might be what you need to loop through

could you please post the full code so i can see exactly what your trying to accomplish

Comment: okay i now see what your trying to do but i dont see why you want a loop, whats wrong with the first bit of script

function Expedisi(t) 
{
   var y = document.getElementById("code");
   y.value = t.value;
}

what are you trying to do by adding the loop?

Comment: With the 1st script i'm able to get the value in first row only.When i generate another row according to that script i'm not getting the value. So i'm trying that in loop.

Comment: okay right, sory i was reading the code wrong, ill take a propper look when i finish work and see what i can do for you

Comment: can u send me more link on javascript for loop getElementById so that i can try more on that script..

Comment: i would advise that instead of using pur javascript you take a look at jquery, its simpler to use, cleaner code and you get less cross browser issues than pure js - http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp in  particular look at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_get.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_set.asp also this is a different type of loop you can use http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp, the whole w3schools site is a good place resource when learning web development if you have time just browse through as man javascript html and php articals as pos